# if statement where object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

getting above error at line : `If lst.ListColumns("ExecBroker") = "ABCD" then` ..

not sure how to set or use the dimension correctly..

```
Sub processPershingManual()

Dim lst As Excel.ListObject
Dim lstRow As Excel.ListRow
Dim ListColumns As String
  
Dim rngHedgeServeTemplate As Excel.Range
Dim rngPershingTemplate As Excel.Range
Dim bHedgeServeRecord As PershingTemplate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set bHedgeServeRecord = New PershingTemplate


If lst.ListColumns("ExecBroker") = "ABCD" Then
 
If shtman.ListObjects.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each lst In shtman.ListObjects
        lst.Unlist
    Next lst
End If

End If
```

Comment: You never assign `lst` to an object.

Comment: i thought this is assigning lst to an object: Dim lst As Excel.ListObject

Comment: No, this *declares* a `lst` identifier as a variable holding an object pointer of type `Excel.ListObject` - it doesn't `Set` that reference, it *declares* it. `Dim` statements are not executable code.

Answer (score 3):

I think the code would work more as intended if you move that condition inside the loop body:

> ```
> If lst.ListColumns("ExecBroker") = "ABCD" Then '<~ lst isn't initialized
>  
> If shtman.ListObjects.Count <> 0 Then '<~ For Each won't enter if .Count is 0
>     For Each lst In shtman.ListObjects '<~ lst is defined here
>         lst.Unlist
>     Next lst
> End If
> ```

That is:

```vb
Dim table As ListObject '<~ consider using meaningful, names with vowels
For Each table In shtman.ListObjects
    If table.ListColumns("ExecBroker") = "ABCD" Then '<~ condition is always false!
   'If table.ListColumns("ExecBroker").Name = "ABCD" Then
   '                                  ^^^^^ this member call is implicit
        table.Unlist
    End If
Next
```

However, the condition isn't making sense; `table.ListColumns("ExecBroker")` is giving you a `ListColumn` object, but you are comparing it to a string literal, forcing value-coalescing of the object's *default member*. For a `ListColumn`, the default member returns its `Name`, so the condition would never be true because the `Name` of the `"ExecBroker"` column is always going to be `"ExecBroker"` and never `"ABCD"`.

Clearly the condition isn't doing what it intends to be doing, but the intent cannot be inferred from the code and there are no indications about what it's *supposed* to be doing, so it's hard to tell what the actual correct code should look like.

If you mean to test whether the `"ExecBroker"` column contains the value `"ABCD"`, you need code to do that; consider leveraging Excel's `WorksheetFunction.Match` instead of iterating all the rows, if that's what you need.